# Java Blackberry "CheckboxField.NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH" not recognized

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a seemingly simple problem:

I want to create 7 check-boxes (for the days of the week) lined up on 1 line using a 
horizontal field manager. Unfortunately a CheckboxField, by default, takes up the whole line. Due to this, CheckboxField SHOULD (and according to the javadoc it does) have a style setting that makes it use only the width it needs. However, my compiler (Eclipse Plug-In) does not recognize "CheckboxField.NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH" and doesn't compile/package my app.

The CheckboxField declerations:

```
private CheckboxField   cf_sun,
                        cf_mon,
                        cf_tue,
                        cf_wed,
                        cf_thu,
                        cf_fri,
                        cf_sat;
```

I defined my checkboxes as follows:

```
cf_sun = new CheckboxField("Sun", false, CheckboxField.NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH); // <-- ERROR
        cf_mon = new CheckboxField("Mon", false);
        cf_tue = new CheckboxField("Tue", false);
        cf_wed = new CheckboxField("Wed", false);
        cf_thu = new CheckboxField("Thu", false);
        cf_fri = new CheckboxField("Fri", false);
        cf_sat = new CheckboxField("Sat", false);
```

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the BlackBerry Javadocs on CheckboxField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/CheckboxField.html#NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH):

> **NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH**
>
> `public static final long NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH`
>
> Use this style to indicate
>   the field should use only as much horizontal space as necessary.
>
> **See Also**: Constant Field Values
>
> **Since**: BlackBerry API 7.0.0

Are you building your app against the **SDK 7.0** libraries?  Or something lower?  If you use lower than 7.0, then the compiler (rightly) won't find that new constant.

Anyway, I tried your code on OS 5.0, and `CheckboxField` did **not** take up the whole line, if you add them all to a `HorizontalFieldManager`.  But, let's say that you do need more control over the field width ...

Luckily, it looks like you have a pretty simple layout.  All your fields labels are the same length (3 chars), so you can probably just create a new subclass that sets the width.  If you want it to be more dynamic, then you could use `Font.getAdvance()` on the checkbox labels to determine exactly how wide each label is, and therefore, exactly how much space each field would need (accounting for the width of the checkbox, too, of course).

```
private class MyCheckboxField extends CheckboxField {

  public MyCheckboxField(String label, boolean value) {
     super(label, value);
  }

  public int getPreferredWidth() {
     // 32 is just a constant to account for the checkbox itself ... 
     // ... make this whatever you like
     return getFont().getAdvance(getLabel()) + 32;
  }

  protected void layout(int width, int height) {
     super.layout(getPreferredWidth(), height);
     setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
  }

}
```

and then

```
cf_mon = new MyCheckboxField("Mon", false);
```

Comment: Wow that' great thanks :)... Just one more (noob) question: could you show me an article or a web-page explaining the keyword "super"? I have tried but it's all very confusing...

Comment: In object-oriented programming, when one `class` extends another class to add to or customize it, the original class is called the **superclass**.  In my answer, `CheckboxField` is the **superclass** of `MyCheckboxField`.  I override the `layout()` method, but I still want to call the original `layout()` method from the superclass, to do most of the work.  To do that, I call `super.layout()`, to make it clear to the compiler that I want the method from `CheckboxField`.  If I just called `layout()` without `super`, then the `MyCheckboxField.layout()` method would call itself: stack overflow!